# Trying to construct a list of a custom datatype in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I am pretty new to Haskell and I am trying to create a list of a custom data type called *Human*. Human is defined like this: data Human = Human(String), so a Human is essentially a String. A human is defined by whether they are tall or short (S or T), female or male (F or M), and if they are an adult or child (A or C).

I have tried writing a function which basically gives me a list of persons of every possible combination of the values above, i.e. = ["SFA", "SFC, "TMC"...]. This is what I have come up with this far:

```
func :: ([Human], state)
func = (x, state_) where
remainingHumans = [[height, sex, age] | height <- ["T", "S"], sex <- ["M", "F"], age <- ["A", "C"]]
allHumans = [Person(human) | human <- subsequences remainingHumans, length human == 3]
x = head allHumans
state _ = allHumans \\ [x]
```

I am getting this error when I try to compile the program:

```
Couldn't match type ‘[[Char]]’ with ‘Char’
  Expected type: String
    Actual type: [[[Char]]]
```

As I am pretty new I am also pretty lost on how to proceed. Any help or hints would be greatly appriciated

Comment: `x` is the `head allHumans`, i.e. the first in the list, a *single* human - it's type is `Human` not `[Human]`. And what type is `state`?

Comment: Is it `Person` or `Human`?

Comment: `([Human], state)` I don't know what you want this to do, but it most certainly doesn't do that.

Comment: Why are you using `subsequences`? Your first list comprehension already generates all the humans that you are interested in.

Comment: Ignoring state, you probably want something like this: `func=[[h,s,a]|h<-"ST", s<-"MF", a<-"AC"]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think since `height`, `sex` and `age` are essentially *characters*, it is probably better to present these as characters. So we can write `height <- ['T', 'S']` instead of `height <- ["T", "S"]`, or even shorter `height <- "TS"`. If we construct a list of `String`s, we do not construct a `String`, but - well - a list of `String`s.

Since you have access to the characters, you can construct a list of the three characters `height`, `sex` and `age`, by *constructing a list*: a `String` is just a type alias for `[Char]`.

We can also make other improvements. Since we construct a list of three elements, the length is always three, so we do not need to check this later in the process, and we can make `Human`s (I assume you mixed up `Person` and `Human`) directly.

You specify `state`, in the signature, but that is a type variable. It would mean that it can be *anything*. Here however it is clearly a list of `Human`s, so you need to change the sgianture to `(Human, [Human])`.

Finally we do not have to construct a `head` to obtain the first element, but can use pattern matching, nor do we have to remove that element from the list: since all elements are unique, the remaining elements are all in the *tail* (and no other element is in the tail):

```
func :: ([Human], [Human])
func = (x, state_) where
    (x:state_) = [Human [height, sex, age] | height <- "TS", sex <- "MF", age <- "AC"]
```

**Possible improvements**

I think the modeling might be better if you define a `Human` as:

```
data Human = Human Height Sex Age
data Height = Tall | Small
data Sex = Male | Female
data Age = Adult | Child
```

By doing this, you limit the number of humans that can be constructed *by design*. Indeed, right now it might be possible that a function contains a small error, and produces `Human "ABC"` (characters not in the "domain"), or `Human "TM"` (too few characters), or `Human "AMT"` (swapped order). This can result in a lot of trouble later in the process. By specifying the domains, etc. in the type, functions simply *can not* generate such values (well the compiler will raise an error). So it gives you "stronger guarantees" that the function is working properly. The function, of course, can still contain a *semantical* error.

Furthermore by defining separate parameters, you also enforce that every human has these three attributes, and the constructor is now *curried*.

It would also make the process of creating humans easier with the [**`(<$>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--36--62-) and [**`(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42--62-) functions:

```
Human <$> [Tall, Small] <*> [Male, Female] <*> [Adult, Child]
```

Comment: Alternatively: `['T', 'S']` etc

Comment: @Bergi: yes, perhaps that is not clear. I've added it in the head of the answer. Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: Thank you for explaining. This made perfect sense and saved my problem!

Comment: Just to make sure. How can I be sure this constructs only unique humans?

Comment: @JokkeMedKniven: this is the case since `height`, `sex` and `age` iterate over collectiohs that each contain *unique* elements. So it can not generate twice the same string.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sent you a message on codementor if you are interested!